# Azure redis cache creation with replica using terraform

Tags: azure, redis, terraform, replication, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create Azure Cache for Redis using [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/redis_cache).

I need to set a replica in the Redis configuration.

There are 3 terms that I come across in Azure portal:

- Replica count
- Shard Count ( Under `Redis Cluster` section )
- Geo-Replication

[image]

I saw that Terraform supports these 3 parameters:

- replicas_per_master ( In ARM, replicasPerMaster )
- replicas_per_primary ( In ARM, replicasPerPrimary )
- shard_count ( In ARM, shardCount )

Which is the correct terraform configuration corresponding to set **Replica count** shown in Azure Portal?

ARM template for setting `Replica count = 2` in portal, gives `replicasPerMaster: 2`

So I decided to go with `replicas_per_master = 2` in Terraform. Should I set `replicas_per_primary` also to `2`?

What is the difference between these options?

Comment: Do you wanna include clustering in your configuration along with replicating this in Terraform? or replication alone? @AnjK

Comment: @VinayB I need to configure replication alone. I have a feeling that what they are asking in the Azure portal is the total number of replicas in the shard ( including the primary one ).

Comment: If you wanna use configure replication alone you can use "replicas_per_master" in Terraform which corresponds to the "Replica count" in Azure and it specifies the number of replicas to create per master node.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision Azure rdis cache creation with replica using terraform using **replicas_per_master** and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Azure Cache for Redis uses the settings `replicas_per_master` and `replicas_per_primary` to set up replication, but they work for different situations in the service. This is how they are different:

1. **`replicas_per_master`**: This setting applies to Azure Cache for Redis instances that do not use clustering. It lets you specify the number of replicas for each master node. This way, the cache can fail over to a replica if the master node fails, which improves the cache's availability.
2. **`replicas_per_primary`**: This setting applies to Azure Cache for Redis instances that have clustering enabled. Clustering partitions the Redis data into multiple shards, each with a primary node and optionally one or more replicas. The `replicas_per_primary` setting determines the number of replicas for each primary node in a shard.

The number of shards and replicas depends on whether you have clustering enabled or not. With clustering enabled, you can use `shard_count` to set the number of shards and `replicas_per_primary` to set the number of replicas for each shard. Without clustering, you only need to use `replicas_per_master` to set the number of replicas for the master node.

If you are not using clustering, you probably do not need to set `replicas_per_primary`. This setting is only relevant for clustered configurations. Since you said that setting `replicas_per_master` to 2 worked for you, this seems to be your case.

The settings for non-clustered and clustered caches are different. For a non-clustered cache, you only need to specify `replicas_per_master`. For a clustered cache, which requires a Premium SKU, you may need to specify both `shard_count` and `replicas_per_primary`. Do not use `replicas_per_master` for a clustered cache.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vkd"
  location = "West Europe" # Replace with your actual location
}

# Primary Redis Cache
resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "example_primary" {
  name                = "demovksd-cache-primary"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  capacity            = 1 # Choose based on your needs (P1, P2, P3, etc.)
  family              = "P" # Indicates Premium tier
  sku_name            = "Premium" # Set to Premium SKU
  enable_non_ssl_port = false
  minimum_tls_version = "1.2"

  redis_configuration {
    // No data persistence settings are configured
  }

  replicas_per_master = 2
  
  // Uncomment and set the shard count if clustering is enabled
  // shard_count = <number_of_shards>
}

# Secondary Redis Cache for Geo-Replication
resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "example_secondary" {
  name                = "demovksd-cache-secondary"
  location            = "North Europe" # Choose a different location suitable for geo-replication
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  capacity            = 1 # Should match the primary's capacity
  family              = "P" # Should match the primary
  sku_name            = "Premium" # Should be the same as the primary
  enable_non_ssl_port = false
  minimum_tls_version = "1.2"

  redis_configuration {}

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]